# Suppress specific warning message

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

First, when doing an `INSERT IGNORE`, why does `pymysql` return a warning?

> /python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1062, "Duplicate entry '2175891' for key 'PRIMARY'")

And second, is there a way to suppress these warnings? What I currently have is:

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=pymysql.Warning)
```

Yet, I don't want to suppress all the `pymysql` warnings, only this one that seems a bit misplaced.

Comment: _that seems a bit misplaced_ How so?

Answer (score 0):

Use the message parameter. It accepts a regex:

```
warnings.filterwarnings(
  action="ignore", 
  message=".*Duplicate entry.*", 
  category=pymysql.Warning
)
```

> *message* is a string containing a regular expression that the start of the warning message must match. The expression is compiled to always be case-insensitive.

[Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter):